# Reading xml using jQuery is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I have an issue reading XML from jQuery. I can load the xml, but I cannot read its tags, I wanted read the "menuitem" first and then read its attributes, my code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        cache: false,
        url: baseUrl + "/sitefinity/services/tafesa/TAFEpagedata.svc/Mainmenu", 
        data: {},
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        console.log(data);

            $(data).find('menuitem').each(function () {

                         htmlString = htmlString + writeToplevelNav($(this).attr('title'), $(this).attr('url'),$(this));
            });
```

And this is my XML:

```
<GetMainNavResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <GetMainNavResult>
        <mainMenu>
            <mainitem title="Courses" url="~/courses">
                <subitem title="Primary Industries @amp; Science" url="~/courses/primary-ind-science">
                   <item title="Agriculture" url="~/courses/primary-ind-science/agriculture"/>
                   <item title="Animal Care @amp; Veterinary Nursing" url="~/courses/primary-ind-science/animal-care-veterinary-nursing"/>
                   <item title="Aquaculture" url="~/courses/primary-ind-science/aquaculture"/>
                   <item title="Conservation @amp; Land Management" url="~/courses/primary-ind-science/conservation-land-management"/>
                   <item title="Horticulture" url="~/courses/primary-ind-science/horticulture"/>
                   <item title="Science" url="~/courses/primary-ind-science/laboratory-technology"/>
               </subitem>
           </mainitem>
        </mainMenu>
    </GetMainNavResult>
</GetMainNavResponse>
```

Can anyone help me with this, many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is there is no element called menuitem in the xml you posted if you change your code to:

```
$(data).find('mainitem')
```

You will get the first element that is title Courses and url ~/courses

Subsequently for that mainMenu mainitem I'd think you'd want to get it's subitems as well via:

```
$(data).find('mainitem').each(function () {
   $(this).find('subitem').each(function() {
        // Do some processing with subitem
   });

   // Do some processing with mainitem as well
});
```

And then the subitems items:

```
$(data).find('mainitem').each(function () {
   $(this).find('subitem').each(function () {

       $(this).find('item').each(function () {
            // Process subitem's items
       });

       // Do some processing with subitem as well
   });

   // Do some processing with mainitem as well
});
```

I've created a github project here with a solution showing this technique:
https://github.com/davethomas11/stackoverflow_Q_39502601

Hosted example:
https://www.daveanthonythomas.com/remote/so39502601/

Comment: Hi Dave, 

Thanks for the quick solution. Yes I have mistakenly refer different name and that was not the issue, when i replace the url: baseUrl + "/sitefinity/services/tafesa/TAFEpagedata.svc/Mainmenu" with the physical location URL such as "url: baseUrl + "/sitefinity/services/tafesa/menu.xml"," It works.

I need to check this with my back-end dev.
Appreciate your answer and as of my query it is correct !